# Best way to extract the tld and domain, but not subdomain? php

Tags: php, dns, tld

What is the best way to extract from a url just the domain (like example.com), taking into account of some tlds like .co.uk?

Is it just with a manual list of the .xx.xx? or do they follow a pattern?

I would say just filter out any domain part under 3 characters, but there are things like .org.xx which are 3 characters

Comment: there's no pattern. ccltds are free to implement whatever subdomaining they feel like. and now that ICANN feels the need to approve every possible TLD, it's only to get even worse

Comment: Upvote to counter the drive-by downvote. Folks, this is a programming-related problem, even though the question is not about implementation details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need a per-TLD (or even per-domain) list. It doesn't have to be "manual" per se; in fact, I would strongly recommend you to use the one from http://publicsuffix.org/